# Files being renamed to .php000064

Tags: php, magento, cpanel, winrar

I've just downloaded a home directory backup from my website via Cpanel and I had a look inside the .tar.gz file I noticed 100's of files being renamed which causes the site to not work properly unless I go through and rename them all from .php000064 to .php. This isn't just limited to .php as other files like .png000064 and .phtml000064 are altered also.

What is the reason for this and how do I prevent it? It's very time consuming just to get a working local copy

Comment: This is a server configuration issue you probably need to take up with your hosting provider. A backup that arbitrarily renames files is no backup at all.

Comment: This is a not a common issue and most likely it is related to server configuration issue. You should take to your host.